# Copy mySQL row to exact same table with different name?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
`temp_info` and `paid_info`
```

Upon successful payment, I want data from `temp_info` to be copied over to `paid_info` - exact same data, exact same field names, etc.

How can we go about doing this? Is there a more efficient way than doing a mySQL query and getting all of the temp_info details as variables and inserting them into the new table?

The info in `temp_info` is defined with a unique ID, so we can use this to define it and copy the data over to the `paid_info` table.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO paid_info (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT s.col1, s.col2, s.col3, ...
FROM temp_info as s
WHERE s.unique_id = <some id that you want to copy over>
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you - this seems great. When using it, we are getting the error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Sorry, no parens around the columns in the `SELECT` portion - that was a typo on my part. Edited and removed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [INSERT-SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).